# Python. get-запрос нужной страницы после авторизации на сайте. (Парсится главная, а не нужная)

Tags: python, post, requests, get

С авторизацией проблем нет, возникают они, когда отправляю get-запрос на страницу, вместо указанного url - берётся главная страница.

```
data = {'login': 'login', 'password': 'password'}
s = requests.Session()
logging = s.post('https://belgorod.vsopen.ru/app/login?loginerror&redirect_url=', data=data, 
files=data, allow_redirects=True)
url_marks = "https://belgorod.vsopen.ru/app/add/studentReport"
response = s.get(url_marks)

print(response.text)
```

Ожидал, что будет html код url_marks, но получаю разметку главной страницы, хотя авторизация проходит успешно.

Comment: Трудно что-то сказать не имея возможности приверить, но рискну предположить, что из заголовков или сового объекта `Response`  (который `logging`) нужно достать какой-то параметр и добавить его в `s.headers`.

Comment: А вы уверенны что авторизация проходит?